# Cordova Platform Add Android Exception

Tags: android, cordova, ant, path

When calling `cordova platform add android` in the Windows 8 cmd, the error message `ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path` is thrown.  I have looked through quite a few other StackOverflow posts related to this problem, but continue to receive the same error message.  I have installed node.js and GIT as specified in the documentation here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface.  I have also installed ant and added ant, Android tools, and Android platform tools to the user PATH system variable.  Here is the current PATH variable:

`%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\apache-ant.1.9.4;%ANDROID_HOME%;C:\Users\t-alboul\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;C:\Users\t-alboul\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\t-alboul\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant;C:\Users\t-alboul\AppData\Roaming\npm`

`ANT_HOME: C:\apache-ant-1.9.4`

`JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

`ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\t-alboul\Desktop\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk`

What else could I try to solve this problem?  Is there anything else that I should add to the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing ant with npm instead

> npm install -g ant

and add C:\Users\ (your user name)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant\ant\bin to the PATH

Comment: I installed ant with npm and received a warning prompt through node.js in cmd.  I also added that path to the end of the %PATH% variable, but still receive the same error.  This might be because there is not an AppData\Roaming directory in the C:\Users\t-alboul directory.  Did npm not install correctly?

Comment: AppData is hidden. Try going there directly. Paste C:\Users\ (your user name)\AppData\Roaming and look for the ant bin folder. Maybe the location is different on your pc.

Comment: http://chrisbitting.com/2014/01/06/installing-starting-with-phonegap-on-windows-for-cross-platform-mobile-development/   try this guide

Answer (score 0):

I see in your path you have

- C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin
- C:\apache-ant.1.9.4 as well as
- %ANT_HOME%\bin and %ANT_HOME% is set to C:\apache-ant-1.9.4

So where is actually tour ant package? 
C:\apache-**ant-1**.9.4 or C:\apache-**ant.1**.9.4 becase in case it's the second, nothing in your path points to the bin folder.

I strongly suggest you clean up your path and make sure your env vars point to the good folders.

What you need in your path for cordova android is

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

To check if ant is accessible from the path, open a cmd and run `ant -version` which should display `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled ...`